# Turtlebot- Random Wandering with Collision Avoidance

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I am a bit of a newbie to all of this so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. What I am trying to accomplish is to write a simple program in which the Turtlebot autonomously "wanders" around. Essentially this would consist of the Turtlebot continuously moving forward until a bump was detected, at which point it would rotate until the bump was no longer detected and move forward again.

My though is to mirror the methods used in the turtlebot_teleop and turtlebot_follower programs to send the desired velocities, but I am not sure how to integrate bump detection into this. Any pointers on how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40187/turtlebot--random-wandering-with-collision-avoidance/) by [legoac](https://answers.ros.org/users/2683/legoac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer is a bit of a copy-paste.  The task you describe is the first assignment in Brown's CS148 Introduction to Robotics course.  Here's a solution that isn't exactly pretty but presumably, at some point, did work... :P

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('enclosure_escape')
import rospy
import random
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlebot_node.msg import TurtlebotSensorState

# global variables
bump = False

action_duration = 0.25
movement_speed = 0.15
turn_speed = 0.5
min_turn_duration = 3.5
max_turn_duration = 10.5
 
# listen (adapted from line_follower
def processSensing(TurtlebotSensorState):
     global bump
     bump = TurtlebotSensorState.bumps_wheeldrops
     #newInfo = True
 
 
def hello_create():
     pub = rospy.Publisher('/turtlebot_node/cmd_vel', Twist)
     rospy.Subscriber('/turtlebot_node/sensor_state', TurtlebotSensorState, processSensing)
     rospy.init_node('hello_create')
     #listen
     global bump
     twist = Twist()
     while not rospy.is_shutdown():
         if bump==1:
             str = "right bumper, turning left %s"%rospy.get_time()
             rospy.loginfo(str)
             turn(pub, random_duration(), turn_speed)
         elif bump==2:
             str = "left bumper, turning right %s"%rospy.get_time()
             rospy.loginfo(str)
             turn(pub, random_duration(), -turn_speed)
         elif bump==3:
             str = "both bumpers, turning left %s"%rospy.get_time()
             rospy.loginfo(str)
             turn(pub, random_duration(), turn_speed)
         else:
             str = "moving straight ahead %s"%rospy.get_time()
             rospy.loginfo(str)
             twist.linear.x = movement_speed; twist.linear.y = 0; twist.linear.z = 0
             twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = 0
             bump = False
         pub.publish(twist)
         rospy.sleep(action_duration)
         
def random_duration():
    # Calculates a random amount of time for the Roomba to turn for
    duration = min_turn_duration + random.random() * (max_turn_duration - min_turn_duration)
    str = "Random duration: %s"%duration
    rospy.loginfo(str)
    return duration
         
def turn(pub, duration, weight):
    twist = Twist()
    
    # First, back up slightly from the wall
    twist.linear.x = -movement_speed; twist.linear.y = 0; twist.linear.z = 0
    twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = 0
    pub.publish(twist)
    rospy.sleep(action_duration)
    
    # Now, keep turning until the end of the specified duration
    currentTime = rospy.get_time();
    stopTime = rospy.get_time() + duration;
    while (rospy.get_time() < stopTime):
         str = "turning %s"%rospy.get_time()
         rospy.loginfo(str)
         twist.linear.x = 0.0; twist.linear.y = 0; twist.linear.z = 0
         twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = weight
         pub.publish(twist)
         rospy.sleep(action_duration)
        
         
if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
         hello_create()
     except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3